# How to test the duration of a $timeout operation using jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Suppose I have the following anonymous functionality within a directive:

```
 $timeout(function () {
     element.removeClass('highlighted')
 }, 2000)
```

This works successfully.  Now, if I wanted to write a test, using jasmine, to ensure the class is removed after ~2s, how would this be done?

I should add that I have attempted using both `jasmine.Clock` and `waitsFor` approaches so far, and in both cases, the tests failed. Notably, however, when I change `$timeout` to `setTimeout` within my directive, both tests have passed, so angular's behavior seems to be at play here.

(Note that using `$timeout.flush()` is unsatisfactory here, as it will only prove that the timeout completed, not how long it took).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Beginning in 1.2 [`$timeout.flush()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$timeout) takes a delay parameter which simulates the clock akin to `jasmine.Clock`'s simulation, but in a way that makes Angular $timeout happy.

So this test will pass:

```
it("timeout test", function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        timerCallback();
    }, 100);
    expect(timerCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    $timeout.flush(99);
    expect(timerCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    $timeout.flush(1);
    expect(timerCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7wmG/2/)

Comment: This test still passes if you change the second flush to `$timeout.flush(1)` and I think better demonstrates the functionality.

Comment: Thanks - can't believe I'd missed this, especially as I've been using this functionality with `$interval.flush()`.

Comment: @jelinson what is the advantage of relaxing the test condition?  Currently we test within a 2 second range- having not fired by second 99 and having fired at 101.  If we change 99 to 1 then the test would pass if the timer fires anywhere after second 1 and before 101 - seems like a weaker test.

Comment: @KayakDave, to clarify, I was referring to the second flush, so the first one would remain 99. As written above, the $timeout is flushed a total of 200 ms (the flushes are cumulative). Simply flushing 100 ms suffices.

Comment: @jelinson Good point.  I was thinking of the middle one- you're clearly right about the last one.  Updated.